# When adding new element to array all elements have date attribute updated

Tags: arrays, angular, date, ionic5

I'm creating an app for a school project in `Ionic v5` with `Angular`.
In one of my services i try to add objects (activities) to an array.

An activity has the following structure:

```
id(string)
name(string)
date(Date)
location(string)
description(string)
participants(FamilyMember[])
labels(Label[])
```

In my activity service constructor I create some test activities using the following code:

```
constructor() {
        let b = 0;
        let date = new Date();
        let activityName = 'activity ' + b;
        let activityDate = date;
        console.log('date on init:' + date)

        for (let i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            activityDate = this.addDays(date, i)
            console.log('date after adding days' + date)
            for (let j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
                this.newActivity(activityName, [], [], 'een activiteit met uitleg', 'ergens', activityDate)
            }
            console.log('lijst na poging ' + i);
            console.log(this.getAllActivities());
            b++;
            activityName = 'activity ' + b;
            console.log(activityName);
        }
```

Somehow after adding a new activity, all existing activities get their date changed to the date of the new activity.
I tried debugging it but can't see where it updates the date of the previous activities.
My best guess is that `activityDate` variable is somehow a reference, but I can't seem to find a solution

I would expect it to create a new activity without changing the date on existing activities.

The code to create a new activity is the following:

```
`newActivity(name: string,  participants:FamilyMember[] = [], labels: Label[] = [],description: string, location: string, date:Date): void {
    this.#activityList.push({
      name,
      id : UUID.UUID(),
      date,
      description,
      location,
      participants,
      labels
    });`
```

Comment: You should read up on [primitives](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Primitive) and [object references](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Object_reference). Long story short - you assign the same reference to all the array items. So each item's date points to the same date object. If you move the declaration of the `activityDate` inside the loop (instead of re-assigning it's value), it will create a new reference on each iteration.

Comment: thank you for the suggestion, I'll read up on those subjects